# What does the number following 'linux-2.6.38.' in the file names like linux-2.6.38.1.tar.xz and linux-2.6.38.2.tar.xz mean?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wanted to download Linux kernel 2.6.38 source files from https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/
but the webpage listed `linux-2.6.38.1.tar.xz`, `linux-2.6.38.2.tar.xz` etc, as well as `linux-2.6.38.tar.xz`.

What's the relationship between them? Which file should I choose?

Comment: As far as which kernel you should choose, you should let us know if there is any particular attribute you are looking for in the kernel (i.e., do you want it to be stable,o you want it to be compatible with RT patches, etc.).  This will make it easier to give you a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

These number represents the kernel version/releases, and give us information about its stability. From [here](http://www.linfo.org/kernel_version_numbering.html) :

> **The first number denotes the kernel version**. It is changed least
>   frequently, and only when truly major changes in the concept and the
>   code of the kernel occur. In fact, it has been changed only twice in
>   the history of the kernel: in 1994 with version 1.0 and in 1996 with
>   version 2.0.
>
> **The second number denotes the major revision** of the kernel version. It
>   was formerly the case that even numbers indicated a stable release,
>   that is, one that was deemed fit for production use (i.e., use in a
>   non-experimental environment), such as 1.2, 2.4 or 2.6. Likewise, odd
>   numbers, such as 1.1 or 2.5, have historically represented development
>   releases. They were for testing new features and device drivers until
>   they became sufficiently stable to be included in a stable release.
>   However, this has changed starting with the Linux 2.6.x series, and
>   new feature development now takes place in the same revision number.
>
> **The third number indicates the minor revision** of the kernel. It is
>   only changed when new features or new drivers are added.
>
> **The fourth number represents corrections**, such as security patches and
>   bug (i.e., error) fixes.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre. Does that mean that the file without the fourth number, i.e. linux-2.6.38.tar.xz, is the stable version?

Comment: Yes, it is stable. But 2.6.38.x are more stable :)